# TSQL select and join issue

Tags: t-sql, join, where-clause, having-clause

I have two tables, EMPL which is a historical employee table to track changes in an employee's tax rate and PAYROLL which is also a historical table filled with employee pay over a number of periods.

FROM EMPL, based upon the EMPL.effect_pd <= PAYROLL.payroll_pd, only one record should be joined from EMPL to PAYROLL.

Below are the two tables, query and result set.  However, I only want 1 record for each employee per pay period, which matches the relevant employee record based upon the payroll_pd and effect_pd.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted.

Answer (score 0):

first of all - welcome!

You wrote "...FROM EMPL, based upon the EMPL.effect_pd <= PAYROLL.payroll_pd ..." but you start your SQL with PAYROLL and not with EMPL.

Pls test this statement first:

```
SELECT
    E.rec_id
    ,E.empl_id
    ,E.empl_name
    ,E.tax_rate
    ,E.effect_pd
    ,P.rec_id
    ,P.payroll_pd
    ,P.empl_id
    ,P.pd_pay
FROM
    empl AS E
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    payroll AS P
ON      E.empl_id = P.empl_id
    AND E.effect_pd < P.payroll_pd
```

After that you get 7 records witch are uniqe.

i think, thats it.
Best regards

Comment: Unfortunately, that is still not producing the desired output.  I know I did not do the best job in initially explaining what I am trying to achieve, so here goes.  The employee table is an historical table that keeps track of employee changes over time.  The payroll table is also a historical table that stores employee pay by pay periods.  So every time there is a change to an employee, a new record is added with an effect period, and should be used from that pay period forward until the next employee change record is encountered for the various pay periods stored in the payroll table.

Comment: what are the key fields in the two tables and where is the period field? for example  march to june is a period, i think

Comment: and what is about John and Fred? emp_id = 'e002' -> John but also  emp_id = 'e002' = Fred? is that korrekt? (difference is between the rec_id??)

Comment: I finally figured out my solution, trying to now figure out how to post the SQL code.  SELECT * FROM PAYROLL p LEFT JOIN EMPL e
 on p.empl_id = e.empl_id
WHERE e.rec_id = 
(
SELECT TOP 1 c.rec_id
FROM EMPL c
WHERE c.empl_id = p.empl_id AND p.payroll_pd >= c.effect_pd
ORDER BY c.effect_pd DESC
);

GO

Comment: add another answer, not another comment

Comment: PD is probably an abbreviation, so what is the meaning of "pd" (payroll_pd, pd_pay, effect_pd)?

Comment: PD stands for period.  So in a payroll period (payroll_pd), the period pay (pd_pay) has an employee record with an effective period (effect_pd) and a tax rate (tax_rate) from that payroll period (payroll_pd) forward.  This way we can keep track of changes to employee tax rates which are based upon elections.  So if someone has a change in status (gets married, add/removes a dependent, that there exists a history of employee changes that ties to the various payroll period and properly applys the correct tax rate to those periods for historical reporting.

Comment: Hi Bret, what is about empl rec_id = 2, **emp_id 'e002'**,  name is John, and rec_id = 4, also emp_id = **'e002'**, but name is Fred?

Comment: The rec_id is the record identifier and any changes to a particular employee id, whether it be a name change or tax rate change would reflect the correct record for that effective period.  If someone is married after a certain date and changes their last name, there is a historical record of the change for auditing purposes as the database will house financial information.

Comment: My mistake for not having a more accurate dataset, as I just quickly created a sample of the actual data for my own testing and illustration purposes; should have included more detail as full names and proper gender.  Anyhow, the point was to get the most current record based upon an effective period date.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of messing around with the code, I finally arrived at the solution which is:

```
SELECT * FROM PAYROLL p 
LEFT JOIN EMPL e on p.empl_id = e.empl_id 
WHERE e.rec_id = ( SELECT TOP 1 c.rec_id 
               FROM EMPL c 
               WHERE c.empl_id = p.empl_id 
                  AND p.payroll_pd >= c.effect_pd 
               ORDER BY c.effect_pd DESC );
```